# Dynamically Create Columns in Block Table From Object's Fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, pageblocktable

I'm trying to create a VF page for reporting.  I'm hardcoding the object for right now (Product2) but would like the column's values to be dynamically populated based on the environment in case the fields are different.  My error is on the VF page stating `Invalid field for SObject Product2`.  Here is my VF snippet with commented out, hardcoded columns that work.

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Results" collapsible="false">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!queryResultsList}" var="prod2">
                <apex:repeat value="{!fieldAPINames}" var="fieldAPIName">
                    <apex:column value="{!prod2.[fieldAPIName]}"/>
                </apex:repeat>                   
                <!--
                <apex:column value="{!prod2.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!prod2.Description}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!prod2.IsActive}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!prod2.ProductCode}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!prod2.Family}"/>
                -->
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And here is the controller I'm calling.  I'm very new to apex and controllers so feel free to question what I'm doing or if you could propose a better option that would be great!

```
public class ProductCatalogPageController {
    public List<Product2> queryResultsList{get;set;}
    public String query{get;set;}
    public String strOfStuff{get;set;}
    public Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldAPINames{get;set;}

    public PageReference testAction(){
        String SobjectApiName = 'Product2';

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        String csvFields = '';
        for(String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()){
            if(csvFields == null || csvFields == ''){
                csvFields = fieldName;
            }else{
                csvFields = csvFields + ', ' + fieldName;
            }
        }
        query = 'select ' + csvFields + ' from ' + SobjectApiName;
        queryResultsList = Database.query(query);

        strOfStuff = 'Stuff goes here';

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `Apex` in the first place? Why not use an actual `Report`? You can export it as `.csv` and it requires zero code.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to jump into the parameters each time.  Plus this is just something fun and a good learning experience for me.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, look at using a `Fieldset`. You don't really want to pull *every* field, I would think.

Comment: I'll do that.  I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the dot in here making the page compiler expect a field name immediately after the dot:

```
{!prod2.[fieldAPIName]}
```

Should work without that:

```
{!prod2[fieldAPIName]}
```

Fyi, here is a slimmer version of the code:

```
public class MyController {

    public Product2[] products {get; private set;}
    public String[] fields {get; private set;}

    public MyController() {
        String apiName = 'Product2';
        fields = new List<String>(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(apiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
        fields.sort();
        products = Database.query('select ' + String.join(fields, ',') + ' from ' + apiName + ' order by Name limit 100');
    }
}
```

and page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Results" collapsible="false">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="p">
                <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
                    <apex:column value="{!p[f]}"/>
                </apex:repeat>                   
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hmm, `SELECT *` notation...wouldn't it be better to use a `Fieldset`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Good point for the general case.